# React functional component re-render not being displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am attempting to learn React and hooks by porting a jquery dropdown box to React.  The problem I am having is that when I select an option, it's not being displayed in the div that should display the selected options.  My code is:

```
export const ReactDropdown: React.FC<IDropdownProps> = (props) => {
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(options.length === 0) {
      if(React.Children.count(props.children) > 0) {
        var optionsList: ReactDropdownOption[] = [];
        var index: number = 0;
        React.Children.forEach(props.children, function(item) {
          var entry = {
            value: (item as React.ReactElement).props.value,
            text: (item as React.ReactElement).props.children,
            index: index
          }
          index++;
          optionsList.push(entry);
        });
        setOptions(optionsList);
      }
    }
  });

  const itemSelect = (evt: React.MouseEvent): void => {
    var item = evt.currentTarget as HTMLLIElement;
    if(item.className == 'disabled-result') {
      return;
    }

    var option = {
      text: item.innerText,
      value: item.dataset.value,
      index: parseInt(item.dataset.index),
      className: props.allowSingleDeselect || (props.isMultiple && selectedOptions.length > 0) ? 'search-choice' : ''
    }

    var currentOptions = props.isMultiple ? [...selectedOptions] : [];
    currentOptions.push(option);
    setSelectedOptions(currentOptions);
    item.className = 'disabled-result';

    if(props.onChange) {
      props.onChange(currentOptions);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='dropdown-container' tabIndex={0}>
        <div className='results-container'>
          <div className='dropdown-container inner'>
            {selectedOptions.map((item) => {
              <span className='result' data-index={item.index} data-value={item.value} key={'selected-option-' + item.index}>{item.text}</span>
            })}
            <span className='result-search'><input type='text' onClick={openOptions} /></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div clssName='options-container'>
        <ul>
          {options.map((item) => (
            <li data-index={item.index} data-value={item.value} className='active-result' onClick={itemSelect} key={'option-' + item.index}>{item.text}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The options.map works perfectly and all of the options are rendered the way they should be.  When I select one of the options, itemSelect is firing.  After itemSelect fires, return fires again.  If I put a breakpoint in selectedOptions.map, all of the selectedOptions are being mapped, but the HTML is either never rendered or isn't showing and I don't know why.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is a CodePen showing the error:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/82dsoldier/pen/ZEYWGMr)